# Is there a way to connect dijit.form.DropDownButton.openDropDown() (or closeDropDown()) on mouse up?

Tags: javascript, forms, button, dojo

In dojo 1.4 default, dijit.form.DropDownButton.openDropDown() and closeDropDown() are connected to mouse down event. Is there a way to connect them not to mouse down but to mouse up event ? I want to realize draggable DropDownButton and open/closeDropDown() invoked just after mouse down is too early.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should implement your own DropDownButton class which inherit dijit.form.DropDownButton and override its method to not connect mouse down event but mouse up event.